# Webscraping from directory of HTML files using BS4 and python

Tags: python, linux, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a website in which each person's details are stored in separate .HTML file. So there are totally 100 person whose details are stored in 100 different .html files. But all have same HTML structure.

Here is the website link
http://www.coimbatore.com/doctors/home.htm.

So if you see this website there are many categories and the `~all-doctors.html~` files are in same directory.

http://www.coimbatore.com/doctors/cardiology.htm

has 5 doctors' link. If I click on any doctors name it will take to

http://www.coimbatore.com/doctors/**thatdoctorname**.htm. So all the files are in the same directory /doctors/ If I am not wrong. So how do I scrape the details of each doctor ?

I was planning to `wget` all the files from that http://www.coimbatore.com/doctors/ URL, save locally and merge as one `whole.html` file using `join` function in LINUX. Is there any better way?

**UPDATE**

```
letters = ['doctor1','doctor2'...]
for i in range(30):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.coimbatore.com/doctors/{}.htm".format(letters[i]))
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        continue
    else:
```

Comment: You don't need to `wget` everything and save it locally. Other than that, what have you tried as far as scraping code?

Comment: right now what I am doing is, storing all the doctors name in an array and incrementing it in the URL.

Comment: do you want the output to be the HTML of the individual doctor's pages, all in one file? Or would you prefer the output to be something else?

Comment: My desired output is the details of all doctors in one CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use [scrapy](/questions/tagged/scrapy):

Create the project:

```
scrapy startproject doctors && cd doctors
```

Define the data to load (`items.py`):

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class DoctorsItem(Item):
    doctor_name = Field()
    qualification = Field()
    membership = Field()
    visiting_hospitals = Field()
    phone = Field()
    consulting_hours = Field()
    specialist_in = Field()
```

Create the spider. The `basic` one seems enought for the task:

```
scrapy genspider -t basic doctors_spider 'coimbatore.com'
```

Change it to return a `Request` object until each page with the information of a doctor:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from doctors.items import DoctorsItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from urlparse import urljoin

class DoctorsSpiderSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "doctors_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["coimbatore.com"]
    start_urls = [ 
        'http://www.coimbatore.com/doctors/home.htm'
    ]   


    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        for row in hxs.select('/html/body/center[1]/table[@cellpadding = 0]'):
            i = DoctorsItem()
            i['doctor_name'] = '|'.join(row.select('./tr[1]/td[2]//font[@size = -1]/text()').extract()).replace('\n', ' ')
            i['qualification'] ='|'.join( row.select('./tr[2]/td[2]//font[@size = -1]/text()').extract()).replace('\n', ' ')
            i['membership'] = '|'.join(row.select('./tr[3]/td[2]//font[@size = -1]/text()').extract()).replace('\n', ' ')
            i['visiting_hospitals'] = '|'.join(row.select('./tr[4]/td[2]//font[@size = -1]/text()').extract()).replace('\n', ' ')
            i['phone'] = '|'.join(row.select('./tr[5]/td[2]//font[@size = -1]/text()').extract()).replace('\n', ' ')
            i['consulting_hours'] = '|'.join(row.select('./tr[6]/td[2]//font[@size = -1]/text()').extract()).replace('\n', ' ')
            i['specialist_in'] = '|'.join(row.select('./tr[7]/td[2]//font[@size = -1]/text()').extract()).replace('\n', ' ')
            yield i

        for url in hxs.select('/html/body/center[3]//a/@href').extract():
            yield Request(urljoin(response.url, url), callback=self.parse)

        for url in hxs.select('/html/body//a/@href').extract():
            yield Request(urljoin(response.url, url), callback=self.parse)
```

Run it like:

```
scrapy crawl doctors_spider -o doctors.csv -t csv
```

That will create a `csv` file, like:

```
phone,membership,visiting_hospitals,qualification,specialist_in,consulting_hours,doctor_name
(H)00966 4 6222245|(R)00966 4 6230143 ,,Domat Al Jandal Hospital|Al Jouf |Kingdom Of Saudi Arabia ,"MBBS, MS, MCh ( Cardio-Thoracic)",Cardio Thoracic Surgery,,Dr. N. Rajaratnam
210075,FRCS(Edinburgh) FIACS,"SRI RAMAKRISHNA HOSPITAL|CHEST CLINIC,COWLEY BROWN ROAD,R.S.PURAM,CBE-2","MD.,DPPR.,FACP",PULMONOLOGY/ RESPIRATORY MEDICINE,"9-1, 5-8",DR.T.MOHAN KUMAR
+91-422-827784-827790,Member -IAPMR,"Kovai Medical Center & Hospital, Avanashi Road,|Coimbatore-641 014","M.B.B.S., Dip.in. Physical Medicine & Rehabilitation","Neck and Back pain, Joint pain, Amputee Rehabilitation,|Spinal cord Injuries & Stroke",9.00am to 5.00pm (Except Sundays),Dr.Edmund M.D'Couto
+91-422-303352,*********,"206, Puliakulam Road, Coimbatore-641 045","M.B.B.S., M.D., D.V.",Sexually Transonitted Diseases.,5.00pm - 7.00pm,Dr.M.Govindaswamy
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This code should get you started.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doctors = ['thomas']
for doctor in doctors:
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.coimbatore.com/doctors/{}.htm".format(doctor))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        continue

    rows = soup.find("table", cellspacing=0).find_all('tr')

    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        print "%s: %s" % (cols[0].get_text().replace('\n', ' '), cols[1].get_text().replace('\n', ' '))
```

It has an output of

```
Name of Doctor: Dr.Thomas Alexander
Qualification: M.D (Internal Medicine), D.M. (Cardiology)
Fellowship & Membership: Fellow of Indian College of Cardiology Associate Fellow
 of American College of Cardiology
Address of Clinic / Visiting Hospitals: Kovai Medical Center and Hospital, P.B.N
o.3209, Avanashi Road, Coimbatore-641 014
Telephone Number: +91-422-827784
Consulting Hours:  8am - 5pm
Specialist in: Senior Consultant and Interventional Cardiologist
```

A few notes that you may wish to deal with differently. I replaced all newlines (`\n`) with spaces because the code has weird line breaks like so:

```
<td><b><font face="Arial,Helvetica"><font color="#0000FF"><font size=-1>Name
of Doctor</font></font></font></b></td>
```

Notice that it forces the break between `Name` and `of`.

If you are attempting to make a CSV out of this, the script can be easily modified to pull only the second cell on each row.

Comment: Yes I tried the same way. But the difficult part is to put all the doctors name in the array for which I have to click through 100s of pages